# Weird auto partitioning partitions

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid

Hope the title can describe my problem a bit.

Ive got an PC with Ubuntu Server and a software raid 0 of a 160GB HDD and a 160GB Partition on a 500GB HDD (what a poor setup :D just had different HDDs). In the ubuntu installation I set up the software raid 0, let the installation auto-part it and then installed the OS on it. The raid 0 drive should be 320GB or about 300GiB, but when i checked i saw the partition mounted at / just had got 109GiB. Here is the partition table (its german):

```
Gerät      Boot     Start      Ende  Sektoren Größe Id Typ
/dev/md0p1      234002790 624623264 390620475 186,3G 83 Linux
/dev/md0p2             63 234002789 234002727 111,6G  5 Erweiterte
/dev/md0p5            126 229986539 229986414 109,7G 83 Linux
/dev/md0p6      229986603 234002789   4016187   1,9G 82 Linux Swap / Solaris
```

Here the part of the `df -h` print out with the / partition:

```
/dev/md0p5             108G    5,6G   97G    6% /
```

What happened here???? I need all possible space mounted at / , wich should be disk space minus swap (~2G) so what are these partitions for? Are they needed? Or can i delete them?
Heeeelp :D

iMPulse

Comment: `md0p2` is an extended partition which contains the logical partitions `md0p5` and `md0p6`. You can find out the mount-point in terminal with `mount` or `findmnt`.

Answer (score 0):

> md0p2 is an extended partition which contains the logical partitions md0p5 and 
>   md0p6. You can find out the mount-point in terminal with mount or findmnt.

Thanks to mook765 I got it. I still dont know how `md0p1` got there.
For anybody searching for an answer to solve this:
In a running system its impossible to get `md0p5` bigger without risky tricks (dont even think about it if you're running a server).

Short: I just mounted another HDD and cloned the full OS over to that disk, startet ubuntu from that disk and then set up the original `md0` disk how i wanted it, cloned ubuntu back and set the rest up. Needed some time but problem is solved.